# What is functionality of Pointwise Equal, Pointwise less than, and Pointwise greater in Swift?

Tags: swift

While reading the Swift Programming Language book by Apple, I came across Pointwise equal, Pointwise less than and Pointwise greater than operators.
Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/operator_declarations

```
.== Pointwise equal

.!= Pointwise not equal
```

I couldn't find any explanation and example on when to use these. What is the functionality of these operators?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The operators are part of [`protocol SIMD`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/simd), the protocol to which the  [“SIMD vector types”](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/simd-vector-types) conform.

They were introduced in Swift 5 with [SE-0229](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0229-simd.md). From that proposal:

> Let's discuss Masks. SIMDs are Equatable, so they have the == and !=
> operators, but they also provide the "pointwise comparison" `.==` and
> `.!=` operators, which compare the lanes of two vectors, and produce a
> Mask, which is a vector of boolean values. Each lane of the mask is
> either `true` or `false`, depending on the result of comparing the values
> in the corresponding lanes. An example:
>
> ```
> (swift) let x = SIMD4<Int>(1,2,3,4)
> // x : SIMD4<Int> = SIMD4<Int>(1, 2, 3, 4)
> (swift) let y = SIMD4<Int>(3,2,1,0)
> // y : SIMD4<Int> = SIMD4<Int>(3, 2, 1, 0)
> (swift) x .== y
> // r0 : SIMDMask<SIMD4<Int.SIMDMaskScalar>> = SIMDMask<SIMD4<Int>>(false, true, false, false)
> ```
>
> here, the second lane is `true`, because `2 == 2`, while all other lanes
> are false because the elements of x and y in those lanes are not
> equal.

Extract from [`protocol SIMD`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/simd):

> A SIMD vector of a fixed number of elements.
>
> ```
> static func .== (Self, Self) -> SIMDMask<Self.MaskStorage>
> // Returns a vector mask with the result of a pointwise equality comparison.
>
> static func .> (Self, Self) -> SIMDMask<Self.MaskStorage>
> // Returns a vector mask with the result of a pointwise greater than comparison.
> ```

Another example:

```
import simd

let x = SIMD3<Float>(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
let y = SIMD3<Float>(3.0, 2.0, 1.0)

print(x .== y) // SIMDMask<SIMD3<Int32>>(false, true, false)
print(x .!= y) // SIMDMask<SIMD3<Int32>>(true, false, true)
print(x .< y)  // SIMDMask<SIMD3<Int32>>(true, false, false)
```